# Is there a way to inject loadBalancerIP to kubernetes ingress from a terraform created static IP resource (GCP)?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-ingress

We use Terraform to create all of our infrastructure resources then we use Helm to deploy apps in our cluster.

We're looking for a way to streamline the creation  of infra and apps, so currently this is what we do:

- Terraform creates kubernetes cluster, VPC network etc and a couple of static public IP addresses
- We have to wait for the dynamic creation of these static IPs by Terraform to complete
- We find out what the public IP is that's been created, and manually add that to our `loadBalancerIP:` spec on our ingress controller helm chart

If at all possible, I'd like to store the generated public IP somewhere via terraform (config map would be nice), and then reference that in the ingress service `loadBalancerIP:` spec, so the end to end process is sorted.

I know configmaps are for pods and I don't *think* they can be used for kubernetes service objects - does anyone have any thoughts/ideas on how I could achieve this?

Comment: how do you deploy the helm chart? my suggestion would be to retrieve the IP via AWS CLI or similar and set it as a value via `--set loadBalancerIP=1.2.3.4` when running helm

Comment: We use flux which looks at the helm charts and reconciles whats running on the cluster vs whats in the github repo for each charts values file. We can set it that way but that doesn't solve our issue unfortunately as we need to get the dynamic value which is a public IP generated on the fly (i.e. we don't know what that is until Terraform creates it). So we need to somehow pass it in as a variable if that makes sense.

Comment: Hi sc-leeds!  How about an approach to creating static public IPs in GCP with the names you want. You can then refer to the static public IP NAME in the k8s ingress resource by specifying the [annotations](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes-engine-samples/blob/fb608f7fe47ff9213caefab7851ac24a699f5bee/load-balancing/basic-ingress-static.yaml) `kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "your-static-ip-name"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest creating a static public IP in GCP using terraform by specifying the name you want like this:

```json
module "address" {
  source       = "terraform-google-modules/address/google"
  version      = "3.0.0"
  project_id   = "your-project-id"
  region       = "your-region"
  address_type = "EXTERNAL"
  names = [ "the-name-you-want" ]
  global = true
}
```

You can then refer to this static public IP `name` in the Kubernetes ingress resource by specifying the annotations `kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "the-name-you-want"` like this:

```json
resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "example" {
  wait_for_load_balancer = true
  metadata {
    name = "example"
    namespace = "default"
    annotations = {
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name" = "the-name-you-want"
    }
  }
  spec {
....
```

This will create ingress resource 'example' in GKE and attach static public IP named 'the-name-you-want' to it.